# Change the angle of the arc of downtube / stem shifter lever to make it an alternative thumb shifter?

Tags: shifter, downtube-shifter

I want to mount the following [SunRace clamp-on shifter set](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0025UJXLK) *horizontally* as a "thumb" shifter on a straight MTB handlebar (22.2mm).  I will remove the left lever and only use the right with the clamp.

The problem is that the lever is not easy to reach because it swings from parallel with the handlebar to straight forward.  I would like to have the angle of the full swing of the lever go from a little towards me to a little forward.

Is there an easy way to change the angle of these stem-mount shift levers (which are almost the same as downtube shift levers) by about 45 deg?

Note (in second pic) that these are meant for stem mount, so there is a cable housing stop for the part of the shift cable housing that goes from the handlebar to a downtube stop.

[image]
[image]

Comment: So, do you have a cable/housing stop that will work with these?

Comment: Also, do you already own these shifters, or are you planning on buying them to modify them?

Comment: @WTHarper I did buy them and found out that the angle is not good.  The second pic is not my setup (got it from the web).  There is a built-in cable/housing stop, as in the second pic, which will allow housing to a second housing stop that is on the downtube in the standard place.  Then it's standard onwards.  I expect changing the angle will require changing the built-in stop's angle, but I don't know if that's possible or how to do it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question - are you looking for something like Paul Thumbies (http://www.paulcomp.com/thumbies.html)? You might be able to do a little modification to mount them on the handlebar with those.

Comment: @Batman: Sort-of.  Paul and VeloOrange thumbies are $75 and $60 half-solutions to getting cheap-ish silver thumb shifters (they don't include the levers!).  Shouldn't there be a cheap steel version of those, such as what come included with the SunRace clamp-on stem/downtube shifters? The only significant difference that I can see is that Paul/V-O have a slight twist to the square hole and a barrel adjuster. IDEAL: Silver/gray colored indexed mtb-handlebar mounted thumb-shifter for <$20.  Only seems avail for downtube/stem, so I figured I'd just move them on top, except for this angle issue.

Comment: For <$20, you probably have to go with friction shifters (sunrace makes 5 dollar friction shifter sets, for example) or jury rig your own mounts using something like hose clamps and maybe a bit of pvc. What are the front derailleur and rear derailleur?

Comment: This question is over two years old and it has no answers.  Could you please post an answer showing what you did, how it worked for you, and anything that may be useful to future searchers?  It is okay to answer, and choose your own answer as the accepted one.

Comment: @Criggie I didn't find a solution :-/.

Comment: @PositiveK  Sorry to hear there was no solution found.  Could you add an answer to the question, and then click the tick/check box for "accept answer" ?  Helps keep the stack tidy.  Its a good question, I'm sad we couldn't answer it for you.

Comment: I wonder if you could use a 90* brake noodle? it wouldnt be the most elegant but you might be able to make it work

Answer (score 1):

Note that there are different levers, depends of the final position. For downtube, head tube or steam, see the ilustration in the bottom of the page:

[image]

Some of them have the cable stop vertically, equal as the tube hanger, and other at 90 degrees of it.

Answer (score -1):

Although I haven't done it with this specific shifter, some similar designs with a fixed cable stop can indeed be adjusted this way. See for example this instructional video for [Gevenalle shifters](http://player.vimeo.com/video/94598777).

Comment: Link-only answers become useless when the link rots, so we strongly encourage people to summarise the information at the link. See [How to Answer](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)